# How do I make the galleries horizontal and no list style type?

Tags: css, wordpress, lightbox

I am helping a charity by building their website. On this page http://www.ukraineaid.org/photos/

The photos in the gallery aren't listed horizontally and there are arrows next to them. How do I make the gallery horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
#sidegallery ul li
{
    display: inline;
}
```

style to

```
#sidegallery ul li, .sidegallery li 
{
    display: inline;
}
```

and remove `float: left;` from `.other-content ul li` should change the gallery to display inline

EDIT:

```
.sidegallery li, #sidegallery ul li {
background: none !important;
}
```

Comment: That worked, but how do I get rid of the arrow? I have list style set to none as far as I can tell and the arrows still appear.

Comment: Remove `background: url(img/app-recent-img.png) no-repeat 0 5px;` from the `.other-content ul li` class

Comment: But I want the arrows for when I need to make a normal list.

Comment: Now normal lists such as on this page: http://www.ukraineaid.org/who/ don't display correctly.